# Assign unique IDs for every row in dataframes stored in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, lapply

Let's assume I have a list called files of dataframes as following.

```
>head(files[[1]])
  HabStruct      SAR      SYM     WYLD
1  23.86667 7.924466 89.67190 95.39818
2  39.13333 9.805045 51.92198 92.27685
3  28.71667 9.440875 79.60088 92.15163
4  32.38333 9.278004 80.52912 93.11543
5  40.31667 8.913012 70.70845 93.45704
6  32.40000 9.518270 79.00460 92.21223

>head(files[[2]])
  HabStruct      SAR      SYM     WYLD
1  23.86667 7.924466 89.67190 95.39818
2  31.35000 9.278004 80.31146 92.84485
3  32.01667 9.192081 68.95144 93.64491
4  40.46667 8.705506 69.15392 93.91231
5  33.65000 9.518270 68.43120 92.04382
6  36.33333 9.871752 65.28246 91.16261
```

... and so on

I'm trying to create an additional column called ID in every dataframe of the list like so:

```
>head(files[[1]])
  HabStruct      SAR      SYM     WYLD  ID
1  23.86667 7.924466 89.67190 95.39818 1.1
2  39.13333 9.805045 51.92198 92.27685 1.2
3  28.71667 9.440875 79.60088 92.15163 1.3
4  32.38333 9.278004 80.52912 93.11543 1.4
5  40.31667 8.913012 70.70845 93.45704 1.5
6  32.40000 9.518270 79.00460 92.21223 1.6

>head(files[[2]])
  HabStruct      SAR      SYM     WYLD  ID
1  23.86667 7.924466 89.67190 95.39818 2.1
2  31.35000 9.278004 80.31146 92.84485 2.2
3  32.01667 9.192081 68.95144 93.64491 2.3
4  40.46667 8.705506 69.15392 93.91231 2.4
5  33.65000 9.518270 68.43120 92.04382 2.5
6  36.33333 9.871752 65.28246 91.16261 2.6
```

I already have a quite non-Rish solution and would want to ask if someone could come up with a solution using eg. lapply.

Using the solution with nested for-loops get's me the right outcome, but I know it's not very efficient in terms of runtime.

```
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(files[[i]])){
    files[[i]]$ID[j] <- paste(i,j, sep='.')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `imap` in `purrr` you can get the index of dataset in list (`.y`) and `paste` it with `row_number()` of the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

files <- imap(files, ~.x %>% mutate(ID = paste(.y, row_number(), sep = ".")))
files

#[[1]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  ID
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 1.1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 1.2
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1.3
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 1.4
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 1.5
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 1.6

#[[2]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  ID
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2.1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2.2
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2.3
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 2.4
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 2.5
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 2.6
```

**data**

Created fake dataset using inbuilt `mtcars` dataset.

```
files <- list(head(mtcars), head(mtcars))
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to your for loop, you can loop through the `length` of the list, then `paste` the index of current `length` with `nrow` of the dataframe.

```r
lapply(1:length(mylist), \(x) transform(mylist[[x]], ID = paste0(x, ".", 1:nrow(mylist[[x]]))))

[[1]]
  HabStruct      SAR      SYM     WYLD  ID
1  23.86667 7.924466 89.67190 95.39818 1.1
2  39.13333 9.805045 51.92198 92.27685 1.2
3  28.71667 9.440875 79.60088 92.15163 1.3
4  32.38333 9.278004 80.52912 93.11543 1.4
5  40.31667 8.913012 70.70845 93.45704 1.5
6  32.40000 9.518270 79.00460 92.21223 1.6

[[2]]
  HabStruct      SAR      SYM     WYLD  ID
1  23.86667 7.924466 89.67190 95.39818 2.1
2  31.35000 9.278004 80.31146 92.84485 2.2
3  32.01667 9.192081 68.95144 93.64491 2.3
4  40.46667 8.705506 69.15392 93.91231 2.4
5  33.65000 9.518270 68.43120 92.04382 2.5
6  36.33333 9.871752 65.28246 91.16261 2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Ronak's answer, but in case your list is named (I'm not certain, but I think) the .y argument would return the name rather than the index, so I think you can instead use:

```
map2(.x = files, .y = seq_along(files), ~ .x %>% mutate(ID = paste0(.y, ".", row_number())))
```